# Why does changing the covariance structure so radically change the standard error of fixed effects in a model over time?

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis

16 animals were randomly assigned to two treatments (control and treatment).  Each animal had its level on the dependent variable measured 24 times over the course of the day.  For each animal, these numbers vary wildly, from 0 into the thousands, with no strong correlations.

Interest is in whether the two treatments are different.

I compared three models:
a) t-test on total activity level
b) A multi-level model with unstructured covariances
c) A multi-level model with AR(1) covariances

c) Had slightly better AIC and BIC than b).

The effect size of group was roughly equal across all three models (after accounting for the fact that the t-test was on 24 values added up) but the standard errors for b) and c) were wildly different.  b) Was significant, a) and c) were not.

In the past, I've not seen such huge changes in the standard errors.

Any thoughts on why this might occur and what to do?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is transforming the outcome variable given the wide variation in its values (e.g., log-transformation if it's suitable).

The second thing is that plotting the ACF and PACF functions for the residuals associated with the multilevel model which ignores the temporal dependence of the observations corresponding to the same animal might provide valuable clues for how to model that temporal dependence. I have a feeling that an AR(1) might not be sufficient to capture it. So you could try various ARMA correlation structures and look to see which ones is most suitable for your data.  I think that an ARMA correlation structure would do better than an unstructured correlation structure in your setting.

In general, if the (error) correlation structure is ignored or modeled inadequately, it might end up counting as "signal" in the systematic part of the model.